# WordPress issues with Conditional Tags

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements, categories

I'm trying to create a series of navigational elements for a WP theme I'm developing and depending upon where you are on the site, you get a different navigational bar...or none at all. My first if statement seems to work just fine but nothing underneath it works until you get to the final statement. Here's my example code:

```
<div>
                <?php if ( is_page_template( 'page-stack.php' ) ): ?>
                            <nav id="primarynav">
                            </nav>
                            <nav id="social">
                            </nav>
                <?php elseif (is_category(array( 9,'news','programs'))): ?>
                            <nav id="primarynav2">
                            </nav>
                            <nav id="social">
                            </nav>        
                <?php elseif ( is_front_page() && is_home()): ?>
                            <nav id="primaryhome">
                            </nav> 
                <?php else: ?>
                             <nav id="social">
                            </nav>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
```

So the first example works as on this page: http://www.aishla.com/blog/2014/my-aish-test/
But the category or blog post page isn't working the same: http://www.aishla.com/blog/2014/classes/
Or the home which should only have the logo and not the social links: http://www.aishla.com/blog/2014/

So the first one is right but the last two are displaying the incorrect navigation using the final else statement. How can I make this work?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `is_category(array( 9,'news','programs'))` and `is_front_page() && is_home()`?

Comment: Display different navigation bars.

Comment: That is clear, but what page are you targeting with the conditionals I quoted? Is looks to me as you want to target different categories with `is_category(array( 9,'news','programs'))`, if that is the case your conditional is wrong. The same holds true for the home page, what page are you targeting with `is_front_page() && is_home()`?

Comment: I'm targeting all sorts of different pages, category archives, etc. on the site. Hit a certain category...display a different nav. Hit the homepage? Display no nav. Hit something else? Display a different nav from the other navs.

Comment: Are you using a static front page?